# The newest of ActionBarSharlock4.0 can't use fragment?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I know that it can used Fragment in ActionBarSharlock3.x,because It contain the support package of offical.
But how use Fragment or other feature in ActionBarSharlock4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the library project, you now have to include the "Plugin: Support Lib" .jar file, in order to use the support Fragment and FragmentActivity classes.

You will find it [here](http://beta.abs.io/)